# Saving an image array with UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I have an app where the user takes a picture and once the picture is taken it should be saved to `UserDefaults`. I keep getting this error:

```
"cannot invoke 'setObject' with an argument list of type '(UIImage. type, forKey:[UIImage])'"
```

I've searched through documentation and posts on here, but nothing helps. 
This is my code.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    switch currentClothesSelection!{

        case "1":
            shirts.append(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)

            //this is where the error occurs
            defaults.setObject(UIImage.self, forKey: array1)

        case "2" :
            pants.append(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)
        case "3" :
            shorts.append(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)
        case "4" :
            jackets.append(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)
        case "5" :
            shoes.append(info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage)

        default:
         break
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

edit/update:

**Xcode 10.1 • Swift 4.2.1 or later**

It is not a good idea to store images at NSUserDefaults but if you really want to do it you need to store is as NSData.

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData,
>   NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects

I recommend saving it locally to disk at the Documents Folder. If you really want to save it to NSUserDefaults, I recommend using just for small images and do it at your own risk :) You can do as follow:

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func set(image: UIImage?, quality: CGFloat = 0.5, forKey defaultName: String) {
        guard let image = image else {
            set(nil, forKey: defaultName)
            return
        }
        set(image.jpegData(compressionQuality: quality), forKey: defaultName)
    }
    func image(forKey defaultName:String) -> UIImage? {
        guard
            let data = data(forKey: defaultName),
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
        else  { return nil }
        return image
    }
    func set(images value: [UIImage]?, forKey defaultName: String) throws {
        guard let value = value else {
            removeObject(forKey: defaultName)
            return
        }
        try set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: value, requiringSecureCoding: false), forKey: defaultName)
    }
    func images(forKey defaultName: String) throws -> [UIImage] {
        guard let data = data(forKey: defaultName) else { return [] }

        let object = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data)
        return object as? [UIImage] ?? []
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
let image = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!
UserDefaults.standard.set(image: image, forKey: "imageKey")
if let loadedImage = UserDefaults.standard.image(forKey: "imageKey") {
    print(loadedImage.size)  // "(719.0, 808.0)"
}

let images = [image, image]
try? UserDefaults.standard.set(images: images, forKey: "imagesKey")
if let loadedImages = try? UserDefaults.standard.images(forKey: "imagesKey") {
    print(loadedImages.count)  // 2
}
```

Comment: Leo Dabus, Can you please check my question i think you can solve it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035210/appending-images-in-array

Thanks

Comment: just save them to the documentsDirectory or to your application support directory. UserDefaults are not meant to store images

Comment: Could you tell me what's the disadvantage of saving image to NSUserDefault?

Comment: Property lists are not meant to store images. Why would you need to save them inside a plist file instead of writing it straight to disk?

Answer (score 3):

Saving blob data in NSUserDefaults will result a huge performance penalty for you app. You have two options:

1. Save image in cache folder as a file and use NSUserDefaults to store their path
2. Use CoreData, SQLite or Realm databases to store images. Data structure of your data will determine which one is more appropriate.