# Appending Images in Array

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to append images in array after downloading from `XML` `enclosure`. 20 images are in `XML`. I want to store these images one by one in array in order form, and then trying to save in `NSUserDefaults`.
Can any one please tell me how i can do this?
Thanks

```
 var imageArray : [NSData] = []
    var imgIndex = 0

downloadFileFromURL(NSURL(string: self.posts.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("enclosure") as! String)!, completionHandler:{(img) in
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    cell.sideImageView.image = img


                    if indexPath.row == self.imgIndex{
                    imageArray.insert(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.75)!, atIndex: self.imgIndex)
                    self.imgIndex++
                    print("Image append with data")
                    self.newsDefaults.setObject(imageArray, forKey: "image")
                    }


                })
            })


    func downloadFileFromURL(url1: NSURL?,completionHandler: CompletionHandler) {
        // download code.
        if let url = url1{
            let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
                if data != nil {
                    print("image downloaded")
                    completionHandler(image: UIImage(data: data!)!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

'I  am getting this error after some output. image downloaded 
image downloaded 
Image append with data 
fatal error: Array index out of range'

Comment: What does the debugger tell you about the array right after you do the insert operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all images and assign to

```
var DtaAryVar: [NSData]()
```

Then convert array of NSData to Data and store

```
let DtaZipVar = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(DtaAryVar)

let DftSdbVal = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
DftSdbVal.setObject(DtaZipVar, forKey: "ImageKey")
```

You can get back ur data by

```
var DtaZipVar = DftSdbVal.valueForKey("ImageKey")
let DtaAryVar = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(DtaZipVar) as! [NSData]

let ImjAryVar = [UIImage]()
for DtaIdxVar in DtaAryVar
{
    ImjAryVar.append(UIImage(data : DtaIdxVar))
}
```

Comment: User defaults is not a good place to store images. You could store URLs to images there, but images themselves probably should be written to a file

Comment: Thanks But first i want to show images in sequence in tableViewCell , i've tried many different ways but tableViewCell not show images in sequence. often tableViewCell show one image on different cells and later it show some images in right cell. After this step i store images whatever is best way.
Can you please check it?
Thanks

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to expected argument type 'NSData'  
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxSENBa2VfZm9ETUE